# How store a bitmap converted to 1bpp to a monochrome bmp file on the Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

After converting a 24-bit bitmap successfully into a 1-bit bitmap, I run into the problem that when I store the bitmap as file it is 24-bit again and not a 1-bit (monochrome) image.

I need it to really be a 1-bit bitmap file for sending it to a Bluetooth printer.

Any ideas or code-snippets on how to do this?

EDIT: Currently, I'm using the following code to save the bitmap:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap.Save("Path\FileName.bmp", 
                           System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

Comment: Do you have any code showing how you're trying to save it now?

Comment: @Joachim, i save the Bitmap with the Bitmap-Class-Save-Method. System.Drawing.Bitmap.Save("Path\FileName.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

Comment: Uwe, welcome at SO. Please know that you can edit your question. I'll add this for you now.

Comment: @Abel Thank you for the support and translation!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

On the internet I see a couple of ways to do this on the Compact Framework:

- In [this related SO question about saving 1bpp using Compact Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166811/create-monochrome-bitmap-in-compact-framework), there's another Win32 API solution available for saving the 1bpp data to disk.
- <strike>Converting [using the PixelFormat](https://web.archive.org/web/20140906075741/http://bobpowell.net/onebit.aspx) enum, but this may not work on the Compact Framework.</strike>
- Converting [using Win32 API](http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/1bpp.html), thorough explanation of the code and full project available in zip. This should work on the Compact Framework, but I'm not 100% sure whether all APIs are available there.

I don't have a CF installation handy, otherwise I would've tried the solutions before posting them.

Comment: The first solution I'll look at me when I'm back. I'm traveling next week. The third option I had already tried unsuccessfully before my posting here. Even while the bitmap is unfortunately the store with Bitmap.Save method with 24-bit color depth stored.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/94dc2598-bc40-4170-8dcb-7215223d0fd3) out.

<strike>You can just create your bitmap as</strike>

`new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);`

then manipulate the pixels and save it using the `Save` method.

EDIT: As pointed out, unfortunately this is not supported in CF.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment thread [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8939599/111575), `PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed` is not available under the Compact Framework.